# How to attach multiple js modules onto single firebase instance

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am refactoring some code so that different javascript modules in different js files can use the same Firebase instance.  I also want to eliminate the possibility of race conditions as different modules are loaded.

I believe that these are the steps that I would need to follow in order to avoid a race condition:

1. Load firebase.js
2. Initialize firebase prototype with authentication
3. Execute external JS files module1.js and module2.js

In code this will roughly translate to the following:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: "<REMOVED>",
      authDomain: "<REMOVED>",
      databaseURL: "<REMOVED>",
      storageBucket: "<REMOVED>",
      messagingSenderId: "<REMOVED>"
    });
  }
  firebase.auth().signOut().then(function () { 
     var customTokenUrl = "<REMOVED>";
     $.ajax({
       url: customTokenUrl,
       data: {},
       xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
       crossDomain: true,
       success: function (token) {
         firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token);
       },
       type: 'POST'
     });
  });
</script>
<script src="someurl/module1.js"></script>
<script src="someurl/module2.js"></script>
```

This is roughly the code for both module1.js and module2.js:

```
var module1 = (function (MODULE) {
    ...
    ...
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(MODULE.onAuthStateChanged.bind(MODULE));
  function onAuthStateChanged(user) {
    if (user) {
      // User is signed in.
      MODULE.uid = user.uid;
      setWatchers(); // This is where I set the firebase refs
    } 
  }
  return MODULE;
}
```

Here are the questions I have:

1. In module1.js, is there a possibility that `onAuthStateChanged` won't fire?  I think that, theoretically, module1.js can execute after the auth state changed in firebase.  Wouldn't that make the `onAuthStateChanged` method not fire?
2. Can the var `firebase` ever be undefined in module1.js?